# Oracle SQL: Indexes not being used

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have the following indexes

```
create index i_payment_amount ON payment(amount);
create index i_customer_createdate ON customer(createdate);
```

and the following query

```
select c.createdate, c.firstname, c.lastname, round(sum(p.amount)) as spentmoney
from customer c
join rental r
on c.customerid = r.customerid
join payment p
on p.rentalid = r.rentalid
where  c.createdate > date '2019-06-01' + 30
or (select round(sum(pp.amount)) from payment pp
        join rental rr
        on rr.rentalid = pp.rentalid
        where rr.rentalid = r.rentalid) < 50 
group by c.firstname, c.lastname,c.createdate
order by c.firstname, c.lastname;
```

The query is calculating the customers who registered in one month before 2019-06-01 and also getting customers who did not spend more than $50. And I wanted to optimize it with the help of indexes.

I created b-tree indexes and With the first try, I wanted to even make the indexes appear in the query plan, but they didn't.

I also couldn't create a function-based index for the payment, because it does not support the group function (sum).
Are there any suggestions to create a proper index, which will optimize the query or even use them?

Comment: "The query is calculating the customers who registered in one month before 2019-06-01".  Your query is not doing this.  Nor, for that matter, is it enforcing " also getting customers who did not spend more than $50".

Comment: isn't it selecting users with the createdate > date '2019-06-01' + 30 or with spentmoney < 50. If not, what could be your suggestion? However, the subquery should stay in order to make execution time lasts 2-3 seconds

Comment: There was an idea to create an index: create index i_payment_amount ON payment(round(amount), paymentid); After which I will compare the size of the created index with the size of the manually created table and choose the least one, but this index is also not used in query plan

Comment: . . I, for one, cannot attempt to answer the question.  I don't know if you simply want to speed up the query you have written.  Or if you want an efficient query for what the text describes.  The two are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any obvious candidates for indexing in the query.

Say there are 2 million rows in `customer`, and 1 million of them have `createdate > date '2019-06-01' + 30` (which can be simplified to `createdate > date '2019-07-01'`). Using an index to find those 1 million rows and then visiting the `customer` table a million times is going to be a lot more I/O than just full-scanning the table once. Range-partitioning `customer` might help, if you are licensed for it and depending on the data distribution.

Possibly an index on `payment(rentalid, amount)` could be treated by the optimiser as a skinny table which would be more efficient to full-scan than the `payment` table itself, since those are the only two columns you need from the table, making the join to `payment` more efficient. However, that is only one of three tables involved in the query so I wouldn't expect a massive improvement.

I notice in your question you mention that you want *the customers who registered in one month before 2019-06-01*, but I don't see that condition in your query. If registration date is `c.createdate` then perhaps

```
where  c.createdate > date '2019-06-01' + 30
```

should be something more like

```
where  c.createdate between date '2019-06-01' and date '2019-07-01'
```

in which case an index on `c.createdate` starts to look more useful, but that's a different query.

Answer (score 0):

Would including the `HAVING` clause do any good? Because, you have all those values, already so you'd avoid the subquery entirely. Something like this:

```
SELECT c.createdate,
       c.firstname,
       c.lastname,
       ROUND (SUM (p.amount)) AS spentmoney
FROM customer c
         JOIN rental r ON c.customerid = r.customerid
         JOIN payment p ON p.rentalid = r.rentalid
GROUP BY c.firstname, c.lastname, c.createdate
HAVING SUM (p.amount) < 50
       OR c.createdate > DATE '2019-06-01' + 30
ORDER BY c.firstname, c.lastname;
```

Comment: The task was to make query with more than 2-3 seconds of execution time, that's why I created the subquery. But the question now is about indexes. They are not used :(

Comment: @Underseamouse . . . And the question is whether this improves performance.

Comment: But the index is not appearing. I wanted to use them and compare the performance before and after. Even will it improve the performance or not

Comment: If index isn't used, then the optimizer thinks it should not be used. If you want to force it, use a hint.